# Time Series Analysis and Recurrence Relations/Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, probability-theory, statistics, recurrence-relations, time-series

I am beginning to watch a video playlist on the subject of time series analysis, and it seems pretty clear both from notation and some of the terminology (such as "characteristic equation") that time series have a deep connection with recurrence relations.

However, in [this video](https://youtu.be/oY-j2Wof51c?t=333), the time series $y_t = \beta_0 + \beta_1 t + \epsilon_t$ is introduced, which I found strange because it does not relate $y_t$ to any of its lagged inputs.  I assume this is because it is a continuous version of a time series, whereas all prior time series discussed have been discrete, but then I would expect something that looks analogous to a differential equation to be the continuous version.

I think I have a pretty good handle on differential equations and recurrence relations.  Can someone explain what their connection is to time series analysis, at a high level, so that I might be able to port over some of the intuition?

Comment: The time series $y_t = \beta_0 + \beta_1 t + \epsilon_t$ is not necessarily continuous. You can consider the case $t \in \mathbb{Z}$ (or in $\mathbb{N}$) without any issue: for every $t$, $y_t$ is a random variable which is given by the sum of a deterministic (non random) component $\beta_0 + \beta_1 t$ with a stochastic (random) component $\epsilon_t$ (this is usually considered "noise").
This is not a recursive expression for the stochastic process $y_t$, since $y_t$ does not depend on the previous values $y_{t-1}, y_{t-2}, \dotsc$

Comment: That being said, in the study of time series (or stochastic processes more in general) one often encounters processes $\{ X_t \}$ where the random variable $X_t$ is a function of the the preceding variables $X_{t-1}, X_{t-2}, \dotsc$. In such cases, the process will satisfy some kind of "recursive" relation. For example, take the autoregressive process of order $p$ (denoted $AR(p)$). This is given by the equation $X_t = \sum_{i = 1}^p \phi_i X_{t-i} + \epsilon_t$, where $\epsilon_t$ is usually some kind of uncorrelated (or even independent) zero-mean noise.